# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'extruct' (Python 3.7 Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, jupyter-notebook

I installed with pip the "extruct package":

```
 pip install extruct
```

```
Collecting extruct
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/ab/9b705a8b2cf0bca59ec1b0729c8b8f80ecc8c79aced20463c1e19fa2bc99/extruct-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from extruct)
Collecting jstyleson (from extruct)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/c1/3791e39d65c39b4e081010f2cf6f9443b7b6b9f6de63a5e458172c5c9376/jstyleson-0.0.2.tar.gz
Collecting rdflib<5.0.0 (from extruct)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c5/77/1fa0f4cffd5faad496b1344ab665902bb2609f56e0fb19bcf80cff485da0/rdflib-4.2.2.tar.gz (905kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 911kB 438kB/s 
Collecting lxml (from extruct)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/2d/642ef7013aa56af52e14b5b7d53c5d591e6d038c9688e06d0f2a20ed26b2/lxml-4.5.2-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (5.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 5.5MB 90kB/s 
Collecting html-text>=0.5.1 (from extruct)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/03/648294dbaa62e55d8622d7b0435b970ca45738498536b92e2f417e3fd531/html_text-0.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting w3lib (from extruct)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a3/59/b6b14521090e7f42669cafdb84b0ab89301a42f1f1a82fcf5856661ea3a7/w3lib-1.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting mf2py (from extruct)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fe/09/116b5b42f5c8cbb1cc43408be9df12fc2bf9fc408dfc9b20311ef4ffbfec/mf2py-1.1.2.tar.gz
Collecting rdflib-jsonld (from extruct)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/17/45e137be0d93b70827fe5529c0400731344a978bc792193d7d9152e6dbe4/rdflib-jsonld-0.5.0.tar.gz (55kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 1.9MB/s 
Collecting isodate (from rdflib<5.0.0->extruct)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9b/9f/b36f7774ff5ea8e428fdcfc4bb332c39ee5b9362ddd3d40d9516a55221b2/isodate-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (45kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 1.5MB/s 
Collecting pyparsing (from rdflib<5.0.0->extruct)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/bb/488841f56197b13700afd5658fc279a2025a39e22449b7cf29864669b15d/pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 2.1MB/s 
Collecting BeautifulSoup4>=4.6.0 (from mf2py->extruct)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/39/1efce3dc73e657c43f436533d49be1491bf8fc830caa70188d73bfd03b8d/beautifulsoup4-4.9.1-py2-none-any.whl (111kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 2.1MB/s 
Collecting html5lib>=1.0.1 (from mf2py->extruct)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6c/dd/a834df6482147d48e225a49515aabc28974ad5a4ca3215c18a882565b028/html5lib-1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 1.6MB/s 
Collecting requests>=2.18.4 (from mf2py->extruct)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/45/1e/0c169c6a5381e241ba7404532c16a21d86ab872c9bed8bdcd4c423954103/requests-2.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 1.5MB/s 
Collecting soupsieve<2.0 (from BeautifulSoup4>=4.6.0->mf2py->extruct)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/39/36/f35056eb9978a622bbcedc554993d10777e3c6ff1ca24cde53f4be9c5fc4/soupsieve-1.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting webencodings (from html5lib>=1.0.1->mf2py->extruct)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/24/2a3e3df732393fed8b3ebf2ec078f05546de641fe1b667ee316ec1dcf3b7/webencodings-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 (from requests>=2.18.4->mf2py->extruct)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9f/f0/a391d1463ebb1b233795cabfc0ef38d3db4442339de68f847026199e69d7/urllib3-1.25.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (127kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 1.4MB/s 
Collecting chardet<4,>=3.0.2 (from requests>=2.18.4->mf2py->extruct)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 143kB 2.1MB/s 
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests>=2.18.4->mf2py->extruct)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/c4/6c4fe722df5343c33226f0b4e0bb042e4dc13483228b4718baf286f86d87/certifi-2020.6.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (156kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 1.4MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from requests>=2.18.4->mf2py->extruct)
Collecting backports.functools-lru-cache; python_version < "3" (from soupsieve<2.0->BeautifulSoup4>=4.6.0->mf2py->extruct)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/da/d1/080d2bb13773803648281a49e3918f65b31b7beebf009887a529357fd44a/backports.functools_lru_cache-1.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: jstyleson, rdflib, mf2py, rdflib-jsonld
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for jstyleson ... done
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/23/ac/3c/5c3d2849c2c9937c1d602b7ba099817c11bc5215abcd07ba4d
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for rdflib ... done
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/8d/f6/b7/f5e9501d0f006fc9fd497c930206952856b2191ab5c836cb97
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mf2py ... done
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/7e/50/a1/7cd28816aacb3aac8185cd1184f5518fa5daae0484dc3674b4
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for rdflib-jsonld ... done
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/8d/e4/7f/9ebcb3e400c694e645c3adba40ef3e9bda78384ac3b9b0d13d
Successfully built jstyleson rdflib mf2py rdflib-jsonld
Installing collected packages: jstyleson, isodate, pyparsing, rdflib, lxml, html-text, w3lib, backports.functools-lru-cache, soupsieve, BeautifulSoup4, webencodings, html5lib, urllib3, chardet, certifi, requests, mf2py, rdflib-jsonld, extruct
Successfully installed BeautifulSoup4-4.9.1 backports.functools-lru-cache-1.6.1 certifi-2020.6.20 chardet-3.0.4 extruct-0.10.0 html-text-0.5.2 html5lib-1.1 isodate-0.6.0 jstyleson-0.0.2 lxml-4.5.2 mf2py-1.1.2 pyparsing-2.4.7 rdflib-4.2.2 rdflib-jsonld-0.5.0 requests-2.24.0 soupsieve-1.9.6 urllib3-1.25.10 w3lib-1.22.0 webencodings-0.5.1
```

That is all well and good.
But Jupyter Notebook (python) issues an error message:

```
import extruct as ext

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-6eff935840a6> in <module>
----> 1 import extruct as ext

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'extruct'
```

Comment: I tried with "pip3 install extruct"  without positive results.

Comment: I tried with "administrator mode" without positive results (sudo su)

Answer (score 2):

To make sure you're installing it for the "right" Python, you can try to pip-install it **inside Jupyter**, by using the IPython magic command

```
%pip install extruct
```

inside a Jupyter notebook or console window.

The problem with using pip install is that you typically have several different versions of Python installed on your computer at the same time. You would have to figure out exactly which one is used by your Jupyter installation, and use the corresponding pip.

Personally, I try to stick to an Anaconda installation for this reason. I always use `~/anaconda3/bin/pip install [...]` to install packages, and run `~/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-lab` (or Spyder, or IPython, depending on what I currently need). That way I'm sure that the libraries are all installed on that particular installation of Python.

Answer (score 0):

In terminal

```
python3.7 -m pip install pip
```

In python

```
python3.7 -m pip install extruct
```